# Why is this question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, closed-questions

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60880/why-dont-english-speakers-give-the-name-jesus-to-their-children was closed as off-topic. However, the [FAQ](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq) clearly states that word-choice questions are on topic. Where was the infringement?

Note that this is not a petition to reopen the question, but rather a request for information so that I do not make the same mistake again.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to suggest an edit in meta, but I think the title should be change to "why is question about child-naming off-topic?"

Comment: The way to ask here is to reword the title. Instead of asking why English speakers don't name their child as such, ask why "Jesus" is not suitable to be a child name. See [Is asking about a name of a product (not naming it) on-topic?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/8224/80007)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your question is an interesting one, but this website isn't the proper forum.  Child-naming conventions are not part of English language and usage, but rather more to do with cultural norms.  Unfortunately, I don't know where to point you to help find an answer.

Comment: I will add to this two things. First, on ELU, "word choice" only applies to questions of the form, "In this particular position in this particular sentence, should I use the word X, Y, or Z?" That's quite different from "Why don't more people name their children Pamela?" Secondly, and more importantly, even if questions about culture were on-topic here, the question at hand would have to be closed as subjective and argumentative, as it is impossible to answer without conducting a huge, globally representative poll of English-speaking parents.

Comment: @Reg And that too.

Comment: Thank you, I now realise that my question is more cultural than language-related.

Answer (score 2):

Choosing a name is not the same thing as deciding which word you should use; the latter is a topic for EL&U, but the first is not a topic, as the name is decided basing on the culture a person has.

As a matter of fact, the name given to a person, even when the person was born in an English-speaking country, could also not be an English name. There are people in the USA, born in the USA, who have an Italian name, such as *Rosa Maria*, *Marco*, or *Andrea*.